# SqlDataAdapter not working

Tags: vb.net, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to update a database using the `SqlDataAdapter` but my code does not seem to work:

```
    Dim sitedb As String = BookingApp.Globals.siteDB
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(sitedb)
    Dim sql As String = "select * from name where BOOKING_REF = 'H2124'"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim c As Integer

    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(dt)

    For c = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

        dt.Rows(c)!OVLREF3 = c
        dt.AcceptChanges()
    Next

    da.Update(dt)
```

As far as I can see the code seems to look okay, anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `dt.AcceptChanges` and it should work.

[`AcceptChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges.aspx) will change the `RowState` to `Unchanged`, that causes the `DataAdapter` to do nothing. `AcceptChanges` is called implicitely by the `DataAdapter` itself after the update.